# Underline missing in Google Search results

Tags: google-search

For many days, I am watching that Google search results lack underlines. Is that a bug? How can I enable underlines in search results? It is very irritating to see that with out underlines.

Comment: See chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/conversation/new-google-search

Comment: That's the new design. Not a bug. See [post on Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JonWiley/posts/AuUAQCWJpki),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are testing a new layout on some regional versions of Google.
You can send feedback at the bottom of the page, and you can still use the old layout by going to the international version (google.com), for now.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/VE7mrvZCfYM

Comment: Strange!! If somthing is working fine and suddenly it's not coz of some unknwn reason?Stop.experimenting google!!! Anyways..thanks for the answer!!